# Laravel Eloquent: filtering model by relation table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have `places` and `locations` tables.
Place could have many locations. Location belongs to Place.

Place:
`id`
`title`

Location:
`id`
`place_id`
`floor`
`lat`
`lon`

```
class Location extends Model {

    public function place()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Place');
    }

}
```

And

```
class Place extends Model {

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Location');
    }

}
```

And i need to find places, that belongs only to 1st floor. `select * from places inner join locations on places.id = locations.place_id where locations.floor = 1`

How does it should be done in Eloquent?

Is something similar to
`Place::where('locations.floor', '=', 1)->get()` exists?

Yes, i know there is `whereHas`:

```
Place::whereHas('locations', function($q)
{
    $q->where('floor', '=', 1);
})->get()
```

but it generates a bit complex query with counts:

```
select * from `places` where (select count(*) from `locations` where `locations`.`place_id` = `places`.`id` and `floor` = '1') >= 1
```

Comment: What's the problem with the query that it's generating through the `whereHas`?

Comment: the problem is that it's strange query with aggregate count() function. maybe, just maybe, that behind the engine mysql translate this to simple join (or join to this, i really don't know). is it equal to join method, that i provide?

Comment: The thing is, with Laravel a join doesn't happen until it needs to happen. It performs the most efficient request possible at each step. In this case, since a join isn't required, a join isn't performed and a `count()` is done instead. If you're just wanting to do this for the sake of efficiency, you're either over-optimizing or you shouldn't be using Eloquent as it is extremely slow and resource-heavy.

Answer (score 0):

does not this works?

```
class Location extends Model {

    public function place()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Place');
    }

}

$locations = Location::where('floor', '=', 1);
$locations->load('place'); //lazy eager loading to reduce queries number
$locations->each(function($location){ 
    $place = $location->place
    //this will run for each found location 
});
```

finally, any orm is not for database usage optimization, and it is not worth to expect nice sql's produced by it.

Comment: 1 location -> 1 place. So this code provide me only one place, not all from 1st floor.

Comment: loop through $locations, i used first()  just for demo purposes.
` $locations->each(function($location){ $place = $location->place });`

Comment: yes, i understand that i can loop, but it's a bit complex for this simple operation. but thank you for the answer, i think that i will use your approach... mine confuses me =(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you have eager loading and you can have a condition:

```
$places = Place::with(['locations' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('floor', '=', 1);

}])->get();
```

[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: sadly, it doesn't work, this code means that you grab all places, but load relations only for those, which on 1st floor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Place::join('locations', 'places.id', '=', 'locations.place_id')
->where('locations.floor', 1)
->select('places.*')
->get();
```